# Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I got a script where if the command is right it will run another script but it returns
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO4xH.png)

Here is the code
Code to get the files

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { settings } = require("cluster");
Client.commands = new Discord.Collection
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./Commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for(const file of commandFiles){
const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
Client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Code for the commands

```
    if (command == "setup"){
    Client.commands.get("setup").execute(message,args,prefix);
}
```

Setup command

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const db = require("quick.db")

module.exports = {
name: "Setup",
desc: "Main command to setup the bot",
execute(message, args, prefix){
    const ma = message.author.id

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Setup bot - " + message.guild.name)
    .setDescription("Here you can setup the bot to do the main things")
    .setColor("#2163D7")
    .addFields(
        { name: '`!moderation`', value: '**Activate moderation features**'},
    )
    .setFooter("Do " + "`" + prefix + "`" + "setup before the command")
    message.channel.send(embed);
   if(message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")){
      message.channel.awaitMessages(ma, { max: 5, }).then(setup => {
        if(args[1] === "moderation"){
            db.set(`setup_moderations_${message.guild}`, true)
          }
      });


   }
}
}
```

And how my commands are organized

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9GYi.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me, the issue might be about font-cases.

you have `name: 'Setup'`(uppercase 'S') defined in your module.
however you are trying to access the value by key `Client.commands.get("setup")` (lowercase 's'), so the collection does not have such an identifier